No exceptions or logging when missing dependency with IHostedService?
A colleague of mine is working on a console app, and we had a bit of a stumble. Launching the app would simply flash up an empty console window, which would then immediately close.
No breakpoints would be hit. No errors would be logged anywhere. No output.
After a few minutes of nosing around, I found the reason his app wasn't working was due to a dependency of his primary IHostedService not being registered. Simple enough to fix.
What I want to know is; why was there no exception or error logged to the console? This would have made our lives a lot easier.
Example (knocked together very rapidly):
//[Program.cs]

namespace FooNamespace
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseConsoleLifetime()
                 .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
                 {
                     services.AddHostedService<FooHostedService>();
 
                     //Missing dependency
                     //services.AddSingleton<IFooDependency, FooDependency>();
                 });
 
            hostBuilder.RunConsoleAsync();
        }
    }
}

// [FooHostedService.cs]

namespace FooNamespace
{
    internal class FooHostedService : IHostedService
    {
        private IFooDependency FooDependency { get; }
 
        public FooHostedService(IFooDependency fooDependency)
        {
            FooDependency = fooDependency;
        }
 
        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //If the program were working, this should display a string and pause for input
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
 
        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}


could you provide a simplified reproducible example of a missing dependency that does not log exceptions?

@MichaelSchönbauer Added an example :)

First of all, you are missing to await the RunConsoleAsync method.
And that should be enough.
Furthermore, I suggest you to use a logging library as Serilog (Serilog.AspNetCore): https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics
This is an example:
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;

namespace FooNamespace
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateBootstrapLogger();

            try
            {
                var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseConsoleLifetime()
                     .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
                     {
                         services.AddHostedService<FooHostedService>();

                         //Missing dependency
                         //services.AddSingleton<IFooDependency, FooDependency>();
                     });

                await hostBuilder.RunConsoleAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }
    }
}

In this case you would also log other types of problems, such as host building issues. See: https://nblumhardt.com/2020/10/bootstrap-logger/

Absolute awesome sauce, thank you so much!
